# Why PhoneStateListener still alive after sending LISTEN_NONE

Tags: android

I'm  a beginner with programming in Android OS that is why I've decided to ask your help. My problem is related to `PhoneStateListener` which should be called depending on toggle button status:

`togglebtn==ON`    -   If ServiceStateChanges or DataConnectionStateChanges -> print a Toast on the screen

`togglebtn==OFF`   -   do not check ServiceStateChanges or DataConnectionStateChanges

I've found that in order to stop listening i should send `LISTEN_NONE` as parameter to listen method, but it does not work

Here's the simplest version of my code:

```
package network.com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.ServiceState;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        ToggleButton button_on_off=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

        button_on_off.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {     
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
            {         
                if (isChecked) 
                {             
                    nw_update(tm , "onCRE");           

                    tm.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState) {          
                            nw_update(tm , "onSSC");            
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state) {           
                            nw_update(tm , "onDCC");                         
                        }
                    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);   
                }               
                else 
                {                            
                    tm.listen(null,  PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE ); 
                }
            } 
        });     // end of button on/off                        
    } // end of onCreate

    private final void nw_update(TelephonyManager tm , String rodzaj) {
        String _rodzaj = rodzaj;    
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), _rodzaj, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
    }    
} // end of main activity
```

Any ideas? 
I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the documentation for `listen()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29), with added emphasis:

> To unregister a listener, pass **the listener object** and set the events argument to LISTEN_NONE (0).

You are not passing the listener object -- you are passing `null`. You need to pass the *same* `PhoneStateListener` instance as you used with the original `listen()` call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @CommonsWare. However, I am still not sure how to implement my code to make it finally work. Within "else" statement I wrote: {  tm.listen(new PhoneStateListener() { (... exactly the same as above) }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE); }    I've also tried to modify instance part but with no success. Mybe you could pass me the proper code, please?

Comment: @Mosiek: "Within "else" statement I wrote..." -- that is not the *same* instance as you used originally. That is a *different* instance. `new` creates a *new* object. You need to hold onto the *original* instance in a data member, rather than simply passing it into `listen()`.